# R: Getting dplyr & summary to show more than 3 digits

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, significant-digits

This fails.  I need 3 digits to the right of the decimal point.

```
require("dplyr")
options(digits = 10)
group_by(MyData, Type_1, Type_2) %>%
  summarise(
  count = n(),
  mean = mean(Rate, na.rm = TRUE),
  sd = sd(Rate, na.rm = TRUE)
)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Type_1 [2]
  Type_1  Type_2 count  mean    sd
  <fct>  <fct> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      X        8  1203. 120. 
2 A      Y        8  1324. 99.1
3 B      X        8  1162. 106. 
4 B      Y        8  1639. 118.
```

I also tried

```
options(pillar.sigfigs=10)
```

I'm looking for a one line answer.  What do I replace the digits setting above with?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This can help: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html

Comment: I think you must a posted a different link than you intended to.  Anyway, I tried options(tibble.width = Inf) and that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the reference I used said to use

```
options(pillar.sigfigs=7)
```

When you need to use

```
options(pillar.sigfig=7)
```

and that R doesn't give you an error saying that it doesn't know what `pillar.sigfigs` means.

Comment: can you link to the reference?

Comment: http://ritsokiguess.site/docs/2018/07/13/how-to-change-the-significant-digits-in-a-tibble/ ? (There is a note that says "*** this doesn’t actually display with more decimals" but it could be easy to miss ... worth contacting the [author](http://ritsokiguess.site/home/) ?